# SQL - assorting data

Tags: sql

So, my school teacher asked me to assort some data, from an existing database.
This is easy enough to do manually, but too lenghty to do it if more than 100 records..

This is what he asked me: There are separate tables. One which is called "CONTACTS" and has 2 colums (ID, name); the second one is called EMAILS; and the third CONT_EMAIL.

It's his desire to group the emails by contacts..
For example:

```
Cont1  |  email1
Cont1  |  email12375
Cont2  | email 7
Cont8  | email 13
Cont8  | email 500
Cont8  | email 26
Cont23 | email 95
```

Some contacts have several e-mails, that's why it shows several times the same contact name.

**Is this even possible to accomplish?** I mean, there is no apparent correlation between the tables except for the ID part.. But even that one is scrambled. The CONTACTS.ID doesn't relate to the EMAILS.ID
Below is shown how the tables are arranged, for a visual aid.

```
CONTACTS
ID  |  name

EMAILS
ID  |  email

CONT_EMAIL 
ID  | name_ID  |  email_ID
```

Comment: Look into using `JOINs` and then look into using `ORDER BY`.  Try something and let us know what isn't working :)

Comment: "It's his desire to **group** the emails **by** contacts" - he has given you a good hint on how to accomplish this already.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `name_ID` and `email_ID` columns in `CONT_EMAIL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT  
    CONTACTS.name,
    EMAILS.email
FROM 
CONT_EMAIL INNER JOIN CONTACTS 
ON CONT_EMAIL.name_ID = CONTACTS.ID
INNER JOIN EMAILS
ON CONT_EMAIL.email_ID = EMAILS.ID
ORDER BY CONTACTS.name;
```

This should work with about any database system.

Comment: It isn't my homework.. I actually help my computer sciences' teachers at some chores that they have to accomplish in certain deadlines. But I have never, in my whole life, even looked to a SQL query..
EDIT: Sorry for the delay, I'm checking all the comments made to this question.

Comment: Even if it was homework, perhaps @FrankPl can explain why that's worse than doing someone's job for them.

Comment: I suggest adding contact id to the select list and order by that field, just in case you have duplicate names.

Comment: @DanBracuk Homework is meant to be done by the student him/herself in order to learn. And if others do it for you, the learning effect is minimal. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions about the StackOverflow policy about this subject.